# Javascript/HTML 5 Video - Detect if video is not loading

Tags: javascript, html

Because IOS prevents auto-loading of video it is necessary to add a 'poster' image to indicate a play button (in this case).

However I also want to display a loading image for slow connections by swapping the poster image for a loading image when loading has started.

The problem is on normal connections the play button shows for a split second before the loading image.

So how can I show the play poster image for when it is detected that no loading is going to take place until the play button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( yourVideoElement.readyState === HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ) {
            // it's loaded
        }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement

**UPDATE**

Or you could use jQuery:

```
var videoDuration = $html5Video.prop('duration');

var updateProgressBar = function(){
    if ($html5Video.prop('readyState')) {
        var buffered = $html5Video.prop("buffered").end(0);
        var percent = 100 * buffered / videoDuration;

        //Your code here

        //If finished buffering buffering quit calling it
        if (buffered >= videoDuration) {
                clearInterval(this.watchBuffer);
        }
    }
};
var watchBuffer = setInterval(updateProgressBar, 500);
```

Comment: That presumes some loading is going on, I need to detect for no loading.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery on this site.

Comment: why don't you want to use it? I don't have a problem just asking.

Comment: Long story but I was using Javascript before jQuery so much I could often solve things without it or other libraries, with a few exceptions. Now with improved browser unification in the way javascript is used, html5 and css3 it is really not a necessary tool in my view. I can see why it used to be useful with it's selectors but now  that can be achieved easily and cross browser in regular Javascript. And also I just like to know the finer details of how things work to have a full understanding of the language.

Comment: I get what you mean. Hope it helped anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check two things, first the networkState and the readyState additionally you have to make sure, that either the preload attribute has a value other than 'none' or you are using an autoplay attribute. In this case you can write the following code (better to wait untill window.onload):

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var myVideo = $('video');
    if(myVideo.prop('readyState') < 1 && myVideo.prop('networkState') != 2){
        //no automatically loading code
        myVideo.prop('poster', 'noloading.jpg');
    }    
});
```

This is not tested, readyState == 0 means that there is no data and networkState 2 means it does not try to load.

With a timeout:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var myVideo = $('video');
    if(myVideo.prop('readyState') < 1 && myVideo.prop('networkState') != 2){
        //probably no automatically loading code
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(myVideo.prop('readyState') < 1 && myVideo.prop('networkState') != 2){
                //no automatically loading code
                myVideo.prop('poster', 'noloading.jpg');
            }
        }, 1000);
    }   
});
```

Comment: On the window load though the networkState is 3 even if pre-loading is about to occur.

Comment: In this case readyState should be more than 0. What happens, if you delay this using a settimeout? see above?

Comment: I really don't want to used timed events for this if possible, I don't think that would be too reliable.